# How to store email body in separate variable?

Tags: apex-email-service

I'm sending an email using one Template. I need to store some content of the body into a separate variable and assign to One field. after the mail has sent I should able to see that content in the field value.

```
  List < Emailtemplate > temps = [select id, body, HtmlValue, developername, 
    IsActive from Emailtemplate where developername 
  IN('PPD_Reminder_sent_at_5_business_days', 
   'PPD_Final_reminder_sent_at_10_business_days') AND IsActive = true];
   for (Emailtemplate curTemp: temps) {

   emailtempNameIdMap.put(curTemp.developername, curTemp.id);
   //system.debug('2'+emailtempNameIdMap);
  }
  String et2 = 
  emailtempNameIdMap.get('PPD_Final_reminder_sent_at_10_business_days');

   if (caseRecord.Submitted_Days__c == 10 ) {

     case casevar1 = new case();          
      casevar1.id=caseRecord.Id;
      //casevar1.Status = 'Pending – Tier 3 Action';
      isRecordThere = TRUE;
      isfiftnthday = FALSE;
      // system.debug('5.1');
      Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail1 = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
      // system.debug('5');
      mail1.SetTemplateid(et2);
      casevar1.Tenth_Day_alert_and_status__c = TRUE;
 mail1.setTargetObjectId(idvar1);
   //   mail1.setCcAddresses(ccAddresses); 
      mail1.setSaveAsActivity(false);
      mail1.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owea.Id);
      mail1.setWhatid(caseRecord.id);
      email_send.add(mail1);
      caseList.add(casevar1);
```

Comment: Are you using standard email Template or Custom VF Template?

Comment: Custom VF Template